# jQuery animation overwritten

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I've defined a jQuery function "countTo" which should take an integer value and animate the html of a jQuery object to the specified value.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    countTo:function(x){
        $this = $(this);
        var start = parseInt($this.html()) || 0;
        $({count:start}).animate({count:x},{
            step:function(val) {
                $this.html(Math.floor(val));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

It works if I only use it on one element at a time but if I try to animate 2 elements the animation on the first element stops as soon as the second call is made, for example:

```
$("#div1").countTo(100);
$("#div2").countTo(100);
//only div2 is changed, div1 remains unchanged
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a global variable `$this` which is getting overritten in the second call, you need to make it a local one using `var`.

Also if you want to support multiple variables in a single call, you need to iterate over each item in the current jQuery object and do the animation like

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
  countTo: function(x) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var start = parseInt($this.html()) || 0;
      $({
        count: start
      }).animate({
        count: x
      }, {
        step: function(val) {
          $this.html(Math.floor(val));
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, dunno how I missed that one. Thanks!